# Memory leak when using ssh_connect() from libssh

Tags: c, memory-leaks, libssh

Output Valgrind (valgrind --leak-check=full ./script):

```
Valgrind Output with memorytestssh() not being in a loop:
==43309==
==43309== HEAP SUMMARY:
==43309==     in use at exit: 512 bytes in 8 blocks
==43309==   total heap usage: 451 allocs, 443 frees, 104,640 bytes allocated
==43309==
==43309== 512 (80 direct, 432 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 8 of 8
==43309==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==43309==    by 0x4C4FC0D: CRYPTO_zalloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1)
==43309==    by 0x4C49023: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1)
==43309==    by 0x486E38F: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh.so.4.8.4)
==43309==    by 0x486E70C: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh.so.4.8.4)
==43309==    by 0x487D9C7: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh.so.4.8.4)
==43309==    by 0x487E0EB: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh.so.4.8.4)
==43309==    by 0x4888197: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh.so.4.8.4)
==43309==    by 0x48845B2: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh.so.4.8.4)
==43309==    by 0x48855EF: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh.so.4.8.4)
==43309==    by 0x48856BA: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh.so.4.8.4)
==43309==    by 0x486B39F: ssh_connect (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh.so.4.8.4)
==43309==
==43309== LEAK SUMMARY:
==43309==    definitely lost: 80 bytes in 1 blocks
==43309==    indirectly lost: 432 bytes in 7 blocks
==43309==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==43309==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==43309==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==43309==
==43309== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==43309== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)

Valgrind Output with memorytestssh() being in a loop:
==55457==
==55457== HEAP SUMMARY:
==55457==     in use at exit: 10,240 bytes in 160 blocks
==55457==   total heap usage: 7,177 allocs, 7,017 frees, 1,743,370 bytes allocated
==55457==
==55457== 10,240 (1,600 direct, 8,640 indirect) bytes in 20 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 8 of 8
==55457==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==55457==    by 0x4C4FC0D: CRYPTO_zalloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1)
==55457==    by 0x4C49023: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1)
==55457==    by 0x486E38F: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh.so.4.8.4)
==55457==    by 0x486E70C: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh.so.4.8.4)
==55457==    by 0x487D9C7: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh.so.4.8.4)
==55457==    by 0x487E0EB: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh.so.4.8.4)
==55457==    by 0x4888197: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh.so.4.8.4)
==55457==    by 0x48845B2: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh.so.4.8.4)
==55457==    by 0x48855EF: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh.so.4.8.4)
==55457==    by 0x48856BA: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh.so.4.8.4)
==55457==    by 0x486B39F: ssh_connect (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh.so.4.8.4)
==55457==
==55457== LEAK SUMMARY:
==55457==    definitely lost: 1,600 bytes in 20 blocks
==55457==    indirectly lost: 8,640 bytes in 140 blocks
==55457==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==55457==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==55457==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==55457==
==55457== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

A sample function which triggers the memory leak

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <libssh/libssh.h>

void memorytestssh()
{
    char * username, * password;
    ssh_session session = ssh_new();
    if (session == NULL)
    {
        printf("cant alloc\n");
        return;
    }
    
    int port = 22;

    char * serversss = "1.1.1.1";
    char * test = "root:somepassword";
    char userpassword[256];
    strcpy(userpassword, test);
    char * save_ptr;

    username = strtok_r(userpassword, ":", &save_ptr); // actual project is multithreaded (using libpthread) thats why i use strtok_r
    password = strtok_r(NULL, ":", &save_ptr);

    ssh_options_set(session, SSH_OPTIONS_HOST, serversss);
    ssh_options_set(session, SSH_OPTIONS_USER, username);
    ssh_options_set(session, SSH_OPTIONS_PORT, &port);

    if(ssh_connect(session) != SSH_OK)
    {
        printf("cant connec\n");
        ssh_free(session);
        return;
    }
    printf("connected\n");
    if (ssh_userauth_password(session, NULL, password) != SSH_AUTH_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("auth not work\n");
        ssh_disconnect(session);
        ssh_free(session);
        return;
    }
    
    //print oh yes worked
    ssh_disconnect(session);
    ssh_free(session);
}

int main(void)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        printf("ran %ld time/s\n", i + 1);
        memorytestssh();
    }
}
```

For the memory leak to happen ssh_connect() needs to return SSH_OK / it has to be able to connect to a device with the tcp port 22 open.

This is a function i quickly wrote to demonstrate which causes the problem, i really dont know what i am doing wrong. Ive read the documentation multiple times and can't find the reason this would leak memory.
Already tried with on other versions as well, its leaking memory everytime.

I tried upgrading / downgrading libssh.
I am just clueless

Comment: Where are you calling `ssh_connect`? Please try to create a [mre] to show us. And [don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Copy-paste text *as text* into your questions. And will this happen if you call the function multiple times, or is this just a one-time allocation (which would mean the library is allocating global data that will be free'd by the OS anyway)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude oops i am sorry, i have used some functions, ive implemented earlier, i changed it a bit, now you can actually see where i am calling ssh_connect(). Should i add the main func as the includes which are needed as well?

Comment: If you change `main` to call `memorytestssh` several times in a loop, does the leak get any worse?

Comment: @IanAbbott , i have now edited the source code of the little snippet to loop the function 20 times, and added another valgrind output which is the result of the looped variant. It seems like its getting worse.

Comment: If you check, or ask on the libssh forums, what do they say? How does your code compare to the official examples? If you try the official examples, do they have the same behavior? If they do, then the problem is in libssh itself, and you should report it as a bug in the libssh issue tracker system. Otherwise, compare the working examples to your non-working code and see what the differences in use are, to learn what might be the problem with your code.